# what the meaning of star of a URL

Tags: http, url

```
        _webResource = WebApp.Start("http://*:" + portNumber + "/", builder =>
        {
            var startUp = new StartUp(Kernel);
            startUp.Configuration(builder);
        });
```

what the meaning of star of a URL?

Comment: Please edit your question (there is an `edit` button, _use it_) and add more details: what language, what environment, ...

Comment: One would assume it was a wildcard, usually indicating 'any string here', this will likely be passed into a regular expression check in Start method.

Answer (score 0):

'*' meaning is bind on all network interfaces on the host. It is the one of the UrlPrefix wild cards. 
Actually, '*' is the weak wildcard. Application that you serves different resources depending on the incoming URL, and the '*' binding picks up anything that wasn't explicitly bound to.

For more detail you can check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364698(v=vs.85).aspx).